# How to set recycler view item width size base on screen size?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want my `RecyclerView` item width and height equal and change it's size dynamic for screen size?

how can I do this any advice or sample code please?

**Here my code:**

```
    mrv = findViewById(R.id.rv_segments);
    list = new ArrayList<>();
    mAdapter = new SegmentsAdapter(this, list,station.getWidthCount());

    //mAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), station.getWidthCount());


    mrv.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mrv.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

**and here is my adapter:**

```
public SegmentsAdapter.BaseHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view1 = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.recyler_item_segments,parent,false);
    BaseHolder viewHolder1 = new BaseHolder(view1);
    return viewHolder1;
}
```

**And My recycler item xml like :**

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_ln_border"
    android:padding="2dp">
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ln"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@color/menu3"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Are you trying to have all your recycler view item in a single screen? Can you explain in what way do you want to change your recycler view item size?

Comment: i think `match parent` will do the trick in the item_layout and `setHasFixedSize(true)`? still your question is confusing..

Comment: "match_parent" your Top Linear Layout, both Height and Width

Comment: I'm trying to do like a puzzle game screen.
What I want  to do just square recycler item. but this square width should be changed by screen size. 
If I use big screen size device square height will be big. if I use small , small

Comment: and for Linear layout children use "layout_weight" parameter to insure they are being displayed where you want them to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pls Use [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout) inside recyclerview item .. Constraints are updated and Better than Relative and Linear Layouts.. Constraint Layout will automatically adjusts based on Screens...

Comment: constraintlayout is not performance friendly as recyclerview item..

Answer (score 5):

Your Recyclerview should take a LayoutManager with Column Span size Specified in it.
which is something like this:

```js
mList.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 2));
```

So now you just need to manage Height of the Items. right?
This will do:

```js
@Override
public myViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
  View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_home, parent, false);
  GridLayoutManager.LayoutParams params = (GridLayoutManager.LayoutParams) myView.getLayoutParams();
  params.height = (parent.getMeasuredHeight() / 2) - dim24;
  myView.setLayoutParams(params);
  return new myViewHolder(myView);
}
```

So.
this `(parent.getMeasuredHeight() / 2) - dim24` is where you can adjust your view "HEIGHT"

And `dim24` is just a padding Integer, you can get rid of it

Notice I used "2" Columns so I devided item Heights by "2"

Comment: Use android:layout_width="match_parent"  &  android:layout_height="match_parent"

Comment: how my recycler item xml should be ? 

I edided my question above and added xml.

Comment: well you only need to set the height of the parent to "match_parent". and also this may doesn't work with constraint layout. sorry for late response. btw, because you were using a recyclerview there's always a scroll you have to deal with